# ¿La palabra "facha" puede tener significados contrarios en distintos contextos?

Tags: argentina

Estoy confundida por la palabra "facha".

La [definición](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=facha) en WordReference.com dice que tiene un sentido peyorativo.

El RAE da primero una [definición](https://dle.rae.es/facha) neutral, y entonces una definición despectiva.

Este [artículo](https://www.forbesargentina.com/lifestyle/pibe-facha-mufa-chamuyo-origen-inmigratorio-argot-argentino-n7899) da una definición más positiva, y he visto "tener facha" usada de una manera elogiosa, por ejemplo, en [este comentario](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRrCMrZapTQ&lc=UgwR2mnu7JU2F38s3254AaABAg) de YouTube: "Razones para amar a los carpinchos: - Son buena onda - No te hacen quilombo - Tienen facha -Odian a los tinchos  - Toman mate - Ya te dije que tienen facha? ".

¿Es solo en Argentina que "tener facha" quiere decir ser guapo o vistoso?

Comment: Se usa también en Chile, con sentido peyorativo y sin él. (Nota aparte. Tiene acá también otro significado. "Ser facha" es ser una mujer de la derecha política, por "facista").

Answer (score 3):

En Chile la palabra "facha" también significa ser guapa o guapo. Se usa en contextos como "tiene buena facha".

Aunque también como dice @Rodrigo mas arriba, hace unos años se usa de forma despectiva hacia las personas con pensamientos políticos de derecha (Es facho, es facha).

En resumen, el sentido de la palabra depende también del contexto donde los uses.

Answer (score 2):

¿*La palabra "facha" puede tener significados contrarios en distintos contextos*?

**La respuesta es SI**

---

Decir, por ejemplo, tiene buena "facha" o mala "facha", es común y es una palabra que se encuentra extendida ampliamente, aunque a veces puede revestir otros distintos significados.

La palabra "**facha**" tiene distintas acepciones tal y como aparecen en la RAE;

- Así podemos introducir la palabra, *facha* (para una comida, una bebida u otro objeto) ejem. *tiene buena facha*, en el sentido de que tiene buena pinta y parece sabroso, sabe bien o parece mono, es decir por un lado hace referencia al aspecto de algo, pero por otro también se utiliza para hablar del aspecto o apariencia física de alguien, *que buena facha tiene la chica esa* o *mira que facha lleva, fíjate como ha venido*, en el sentido de descuidado o extravagante.

En este sentido la palabra "**facha**" sería un préstamo italiano del S. XVII del italiano "*faccia*" "cara" (faz), procedente del latín "*facies*" con el significado de **figura o aspecto**.

- Por otro lado la palabra "**facha**" del italiano "fascio" y "fascista" tiene actualmente un **sesgo político**, aunque en un principio designaba de forma despectiva a una persona "fascista", es decir, una persona con ideología política reaccionaria. Actualmente algunos la utilizan como insulto o de forma peyorativa para referirse a aquellos partidos o personas que son de derechas o comulgan con estas ideas. Últimamente el conceptos se ha ido radicalizando y "fascista o facha", sería todo aquel que este en contra o no simpatice con las ideas de izquierdas.

Comment: Y "tener facha" para decir "guapo" -- ¿esta se encuentra por muchas partes también?

Comment: La expresión, "Tener facha", por si sola puede conducir a errores, pues "facha" (la fachada) puede ser positiva o negativa. Si por ej. decimos, el amigo que vino ayer contigo, tenía una facha, menudo hombre. Entendemos que era un hombre atractivo, guapo, elegante..de igual manera al decir, qué buena facha tiene tu amigo, preséntamelo. En estos casos "facha" es positivo, es guapo. Si por el contrarío decimos qué facha tan  ridícula tenía tu amigo ayer, o que facha tan mala tenía el profesor en clase, estaba dejado. En estos casos el sentido es peyorativo de feo o mala pinta. ¡Feliz Navidad!

Comment: A veces en gran parte de Iberoamérica también se utiliza la expresión "fachero" / "fachera" para una persona bella, vistosa, guapo/a o que en general le gusta ir elegante, vestirse bien o cuidarse.

Comment: El fascismo italiano toma su nombre del *fascio* o fasces romano (y anterior) que usaba como símbolo; actualmente es sinónimo de una "persona con ideología política reaccionaria". Fascio en italiano suena como "facho" en español, es probable que de ahí venga la relación.